# dynamically build data string for ajax call that contains html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For a long time I have been using the below code to dynamically build a string representing key value pairs to be used in an ajax call.

This has been working quite well for my originally simple needs.

```
// make an array of strings representing key value pairs
var feedback = ['var1=val1', 'var2=val2', 'var3=val3' ]; 
// join each pair with "&" seperating them
var dataString = feedback.join('&');         

// make an ajax call 
  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "_php/feedback.php",
data: dataString, //pass in the built vars 
success: function() {
    // do stuff...
}
});
```

I now have the need to send html as values in the data string. First thing I notice is that html containing '&' is going to be an issue so I made a simple test using **`var2=<span>&nbsp;val2<span>`**:

```
  // make any array of strings representing key value pairs
      var feedback = ['var1=val1', 'var2=<span>&nbsp;val2<span>', 'var3=val3' ]; 
      // join each pair with "&" seperating them
      var dataString = feedback.join('&');       

      // amke an ajax call 
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "feedback.php",
      data: dataString, //pass in the built vars 
      success: function(info) {
         $('#result').html(info);
      }
      });
```

Then in my php page:

```
<?php

$var1=$_POST['var1'];
$var2=$_POST['var2'];
$var3=$_POST['var3'];

echo $var1.'<br>'.$var2.'<br>'.$var3.'<br>';
?>
```

I want the script to return:

```
val1<br><span>&nbsp;val2<span><br>val3<br>
```

But, just as I suspected, the return output was:

```
val1<br><span><br>val3<br>
```

A quick look in the inspector shows:
[image]

**How can I dynamically create a string to use with `data: dataString,` in an ajax call that may contain html?**

I tried searching for this but all I can find is "how to send post data with an html form" which clearly doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// make an array of strings representing key value pairs
var feedback = ['var1=val1', 'var2=val2', 'var3=val3' ]; 
// to apply encodeURIComponent function for each cell
feedback = feedback.map(function (cell) 
{
    var res = cell.split('=');
    return res[0] + '=' + encodeURIComponent (res[1]);
}) ;

// join each pair with "&" seperating them
```

var dataString = feedback.join('&');

```
 $.ajax({
     type    : "POST",
      url    : "feedback.php",
      data   : dataString,
      success: function(info) {
          $('#result').html(info);
      }
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns the same `val1<br><span><br>val3<br>`

Comment: @DelightedD0D you have to clear your browser's cache : user CTRL+R

Comment: I did try that I even tried in a different browser altogether, same result. Do I maybe need to encode the portion of the string before I join them al together?

Comment: +1 for the push in the right direction, `encodeURIComponent()` does the trick if I apply it to just the value then put the strings together

Comment: @DelightedD0D good to know that i helped you, i edited my answer with your correction

Comment: Change it to like this http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/5vykx0tm/  and I'll accept it.  It only works if I apply it to just the variable with the HTML, if I apply it to the whole string, it doesnt work.

Comment: @DelightedD0D i updated my answer, and tested map() method on IE,Chrome & Firefox and it works fine :)